# Chrome 48 says "authenticated using AES_128_GCM", but no such thing in cipher-list

Tags: encryption, lighttpd

so my chrome version is 48, my lighttpd is 1.4.28 (a little bit old but cannot upgrade for now.)

in lighttpd.conf,

```
ssl.cipher-list = "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4"
```

Chrome 48 says sth. like "obsolete cipher list, authenticated using AES_128_GCM, using RSA key exchange". But i don't see any AES128 at all in that list.

So how to solve this obsolete cipher list problem please ?

Comment: `AESGCM` is probably synonymous with `AES_128_GCM`, but there is no `RSA-AESGCM`, which is the stranger thing in my opinion

Comment: Run `openssl ciphers -v 'cipherlist'` on your system and see what ciphers the string actually gives on your system. On my system this cipher is actually activated by `:HIGH`.